# Property 'userid' does not exist on type '{ }'. TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-router

In my react-app, when I try to retain the params in router, getting a error as :

`Property 'userid' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339` in compile it's throws and stop the process. what is the correct way to fix this?

here is the code :

```
import { FC } from "react";
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ScreenC: FC = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { userid } = useParams(); //here the error exist

  const goBack = () => {
    history.goBack();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{userid}</div>
      <button onClick={goBack}>Go back </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ScreenC;
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-golick-ewyh4?file=/src/ScreenC.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add type of `userid` like this:

```
const { userid } = useParams<{userid : string}>()
```

Comment: @Vient, it works. but is this the correct way to handle this? is I missed or need to add any `@types` - part? thanks for your quick replay